# how to execute asynctask and start an activity on button click at the same time

Tags: android, android-asynctask

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    get_Brand = spBrand.getSelectedItem().toString();
    get_Model = spModel.getSelectedItem().toString();
    get_Category = spCategory.getSelectedItem().toString();
    Intent intentToProductList = new Intent(ActivityApplicationChart.this, ActivityAppChartToCategoryList.class);
    intentToProductList.putExtra("Brand_Name", get_Brand);
    intentToProductList.putExtra("Model_Name", get_Model);
    intentToProductList.putExtra("Category_Name", get_Category);
    startActivity(intentToProductList);
}
```

I have provided here code for button click. As soon as I click on button, new Activity will get start and also an asynctask will be executed. How will it work? Please help me experts :)

Comment: what you want to do in async task?

Comment: where have you executed `Async` task?

Comment: in Oncreate() of ActivityAppChartToCategoryList.class get the intent values that you sent in previous activity. call asynctask as soon as you setContentVIew

Comment: my asynctask will execute webservice to show brand wise and model wise category list on next activity. And  I will call execute method of asynctask on button click event. Will it work?

Answer (score 0):

execute asynctask on click button and write intent code in onPost method of asynctask .

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you are moving from activity A to B and you are starting asynctask T  at activity A, then asynctask T will continue to run in background while activity B is visible. Now when you press back button from activity B, onPostexecute of asynctask T will execute and Activity A will have new set of data or updated view.

Answer (score 0):

First In button click, you can execute the Async task for call web service in doInBackground method and than after call Intent in OnPostExecute method 
So after completing the background task(WebService) your postExecute task call (Intent) automatically.

Answer (score 0):

It is sample logic! You can execute `AsyncTask` before call `startActivity(intentToProductList);`, 
or you can call method to start activity in abstract method `onPreExecute` of AsyncTask.